# Trying to reverse an image stored in an array in Java

Tags: java, arrays, reverse

I need to reverse an image of a given length and width stored in double[] img;
This is my first time working with arrays. Instructions are to have nested for loops, outer loops over the y(rows) and inner loops over x(columns) and reverse each horizantal array.
this is what i have and it is not working.

```
width = ImageLibrary.getImageWidth();
height = ImageLibrary.getImageHeight();

  for(i = 0; i < width ; i++){
    for(j = 0; j < height ; j++){
       for(int k = 0; k < img.length/2; k++){
           double temp = img[k];
           img[i] = img[img.length - k - 1];
           img[img.length - k - 1] = temp;
}
    }
  }
```

I am really unsure of what to do? when it says to reverse the horizantal array, am I doing that correctly?
Thank you

Comment: Explain what you mean by "reverse"? Like mirrored horizontally or vertically? Or both? Or something completely different?

Comment: Sorry, yes mirrored vertically i think. Say an image of a cat looking to the right, now it will be mirrored to it is looking to the left.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is more like this

```
width = ImageLibrary.getImageWidth();
height = ImageLibrary.getImageHeight();

// Loop from the top of the image to the bottom
for (y = 0; y < height ; y++) {

    // Loop halfway across each row because going all the way will result
    // in all the numbers being put back where they were to start with
    for (x = 0; x < width / 2 ; x++) {

        // Here, `y * width` gets the row, and `+ x` gets position in that row
        double temp = img[y * width + x];

        // Here, `width - x - 1` gets x positions in from the end of the row
        // Subtracting 1 because of 0-based index
        img[y * width + x] = img[y * width + (width - x - 1)];
        img[y * width + (width - x - 1)] = temp;
    }
}
```

This will mirror the image so now the left side is the right side, and the right side is the left side

Comment: Thank you for your answer but it gives me a very stretched and distorted image unfortunately

Comment: Stretched and distorted? Strange, but I'll keep thinking of how to get it to work...

Comment: I know exactly what I did wrong. I was assuming an image of square dimensions... Updated answer. Let me know if it works now :)